# For each using linq how to use else

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have code that is checking for specific files and then if condition is fulfilled its going in to stats.matching.... I am using this for each linq:

```
  For Each file As String In From file1 In Stats.FoundFiles 
                             Let ftpFile = Utils.ToLowerWithoutSpaces(file1) 
                             Where ftpFile.Contains(currentReportName) 
                             Select file1
      Stats.MatchingFiles.Add(file)
  Next
```

The question is how to implement else here.

Comment: A `For Each` is a loop, it has no `Else`, what do you want to achieve? Do you have a `Stats.MisMatchingFiles` collection which you also want to fill? Or do you want to handle the case that there is no file matching?

Comment: yes i have another list Stats.MisMatchingFiles list which i would like to fill in if file doesnt pass over this for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to fill another collection with files that don't contain the word.

```
Dim matching = From file1 In Stats.FoundFiles 
               Let ftpFile = Utils.ToLowerWithoutSpaces(file1) 
               Where ftpFile.Contains(currentReportName)
Dim mismatching = From file1 In Stats.FoundFiles 
                  Let ftpFile = Utils.ToLowerWithoutSpaces(file1) 
                  Where Not ftpFile.Contains(currentReportName)

For Each file As String In matching 
    Stats.MatchingFiles.Add(file)
Next
For Each file As String In mismatching 
    Stats.MismatchingFiles.Add(file)
Next
```

That is the simple solution, you could also use `Except` which is more efficient:

```
Dim mismatching = Stats.FoundFiles.Except(matching)
```

Comment: Sorry, why looping same collection twice and after that looping each result collection again is good solution instead of looping `FoundFiles` only once and write result while looping?

Comment: @Fabio: the LINQ queries don't loop (or enumerate) the collections twice, since `Enumerable.Where` is using deferred execution it will be enumerated at the `For Each`, the queries are just the definiton but not the execution. But of course this is not performance optimized, just the easiest approach since it just inverts the condition to get the non-matching files. I wanted to keep it simple. The most efficient approach is `Except` or a single loop like you have mentioned.

Comment: Ok, but `Stats.FoundFiles` will be enumerated twice while adding items to the `Stats.MatchingFiles` and to the `Stats.MismatchingFiles`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case original `For Each` loop with `If... Else` will be simple enough approach
And loop a `Stats.FoundFile` only once

```
For Each file As String In Stats.FoundFiles 
    Dim ftpFile As String = Utils.ToLowerWithoutSpaces(file) 
    If ftpFile.Contains(currentReportName) = True Then
        Stats.MatchingFiles.Add(file)
    Else
        Stats.MismatchingFiles.Add(file)
    End If
Next
```

Or if you are fan of LINQ and must to use it, then you can play with `Aggregate` extension method

```
Stats.FoundFiles.Aggregate(String.Empty, 
                           Function(seed, file)                                   
                               If Utils.ToLowerWithoutSpaces(file).Contains(file) Then
                                   Stats.MatchingFiles.Add(file)
                               Else
                                   Stats.MismatchingFiles.Add(file)
                               End If
                               Return String.Empty
                           End Function)
```